# How to get Average of Points in Polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1

There are many number of polygon in my study area and in each polygon I have 16 points available.Is there any way to get multiple value of points to a single point.

Comment: HI! Welcome to GIS.Stackexchange. Your question in its current state is unclear. Can you please edit it and details like: What you mean by average, and what you have tried so far? This post can provide pointers on improving this question: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question

Comment: I'm thinking you need to do 'Intersect' or 'Identity' to get the polygon values onto the points and then 'summary statistics' to calculate the average, using the OID/FID of the polygon as a case field. If you don't have an advanced level of license you can do 'spatial join', export as shapefile then open the .dbf in excel and pivot table to get the mean.

Comment: Think of "about a paragraph" as being the minimum length for any Question (or Answer).

Answer (score 3):

If you use the tool "spatial join", you an join the attributes of the points to your polygon. Doing this, select the ONe_TO_ONE option and you will be able to merge the attributes of your points. One of the [merge rules](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z00000014000000) is "mean", so this is what you need to get the mean of the attributes of the points in each polygon.

The second step is to create a single point. If you have an advanced licence, you can simply use feature to point. Otherwise, you need to add two fields and use the field calculator on your polygon, with calculate geometry for the coordinates of the centroid. Finally, use "make XY event layer" and you have your single point.